# How to override Qt member function with .dll injection

Tags: c++, qt, dll, code-injection

I'm trying to provide a windows version of some code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openhmitester/) which is used to record Qt (4.7) events.  The target application is Qt based as is the code that does the injection, fwiw.  The linux version uses library preloading to override QWidget::x11event as a starting point to the recording code.

I have tried to do the same, using winEvent as the appropriate equivalent to x11event. I am using dll injection which as far as I can tell is successful. The dll is listed in loaded modules in the debugger and the loading routines are all successful.

However I am never seeing my winEvent being called. I have tried overriding other functions with the same result.

I am new to dll creation, let alone injection, so may be missing an important step somewhere, but my suspicions are raised by compiler warnings when I build the .dll containing my winEvent implementation; I get "warning C4273: 'QWidget::winEvent' : inconsistent dll linkage". The dll compiles successfully though. At the moment I simply have

```
bool QWidget::winEvent ( MSG *message, long *result)
{
 // my code
}
```

in one of the cpp files in my .dll. Is this enough?

Comment: If you want to override a function in an open source application, why not just change the source code yourself? What's the point of dealing with the hassle of DLL injection?

Comment: The open source code records user actions in any Qt target application by using library preloading, in linux. The nearest I can get to that in windows is dll injection.

Answer (score 0):

How does Qt make its classes DLL export?

```
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QWidget : public QObject, public QPaintDevice
```

or maybe earlier Qt exposes same class with:

```
class Q_GUI_EXPORT QWidget : public QObject, public QPaintDevice
```

What is Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT? After all #ifdef/#define redirections for dynamic Qt you should get its value like:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

And that is set with your normal Qt application project. For that DLL injection project (I guess) before including Qt header you may try to do:

```
#define Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

or

```
#define Q_GUI_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

or
    *Figure out* how to make the value Q_GUI_EXPORT to be __declspec(dllexport)

- *And you should double check on that macros Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT with specific Qt version you attempt to inject with your DLL. I peeked at Qt 5.3.2 source code.*
- *Mind DLL export and import paradigm, for your app project it is import, for the DLL exposing functions it is export. Just like the international trade.*

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't appear to help unfortunately. In the .cpp file in which I redefine QWidget::winEvent, I have other Qt code which should be pulling in those #defines, so I'm not too surprised.

Comment: Then it is unclear how exactly that DLL project implemented? What does the file with QWidget::winEvent include?

Comment: In Qt 4.7, QWidget is defined as: class Q_GUI_EXPORT QWidget : public QObject, public QPaintDevice, and Q_GUI_EXPORT is defined as #    define Q_GUI_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT, which in turn is #define Q_DECL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport) (sorry I'm not clear how to format this comment without causing it to post!). This seems at odds with your dllexport.. any ideas?  My code that overrides QWidget::winEvent includes <QWidget>,  and some boost stuff.

Comment: In your DLL project you should have DLL export. In your app project there is DLL import.

Comment: No luck so far I'm afraid. It seems like I should be able to use QT_MAKEDLL in order for this to work without having to override anything in my file specifically, but so far none of the various preprocessor definitions have helped. hrmph.